# Close the window when Chrome print dialog is clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to close the current tab in Chrome when the `print` button in Print Dialog is clicked by the user. I tried with `window.print()` and `setTimeout()`, but this will close the dialog even if the print is canceled by the `CANCEL` button.
Is there is any solution for this?

This is what I have done so far:

```
function printThis(){
    window.print();
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.close();
    },5000);
}
```

Comment: talk is cheap, show me the code.

Comment: what i want is, when we click print button from print dialog (ctrl + p), the currently using tab should be closed.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried ? I believe you need to stop that event from implementing that default behaviour , you would need to `preventDefault()` method.

Comment: the code is shared above

Comment: Why don't you remove the `window.print()` command from the function? That way it wll close after 5 seconds after that function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

please use this code.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", function(event) { ... });
//or
window.onbeforeprint = function(event) { ... };
```

`window.onbeforeprint` will be called when press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or else for opening print dialog

e.g

```
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", 
                        function(event) {
                            window.close();
                        });
```

or if you want to close window after print button pressed, please use `window.onafterprint` like this

```
window.onafterprint = function(){
   window.close()
}
```

Comment: this will close if i click  cancel button also. i want only to close after the print button is clicked

Comment: then you may use `window.onafterprint` event like this
`window.onafterprint = function(){
   window.close()
}`

Comment: even i checked with onafterprint . here problem is if i click cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the this method in onload, once this print dialog is dismissed the alert prompt will automatically be called and ask the user whether print or not if print has been done, the user will be automatically redirected to the page.

If you want to close the window you should open the particular window by `window.open` method, you cannot close the window by just opening by URL or redirects.

Example:

```
window.open("https://yourside.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

Then you can call `window.close` in the window which is opened by window.open.

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.print();
    setTimeout(function(){ if(confirm("Have you printed ?")) { window.location.href="/your_page"; } }, 1);
}
```

Comment: this wont work in my situation. here i can click print and click no for confirmation also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onafterprint` event:

```
window.onafterprint = function(){ window.close() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple!
on print page (In my case it is "print-page.html") use this script -

```
<script>
window.onafterprint = function(){
window.close()
}
</script>
```

It will close the new tab when the user clicked the print/cancel button! Tested on chrome and works fine.

Make sure you have already called the print interface using this method -

```
<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open('print-page.html','popUpWindow','height=687,width=1057,left=10,top=10,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no'); return false;" />
```

Best of luck!