# Exit after window.print()

Tags: javascript

so i opened a new window and it will popup the window.print() stuff and i want the window to close i have to exit the window ( not closing it ) and click the tab then take a few second or less to close. This is my coding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printreport(){
    setTimeout(function () { window.print(); }, 500);
    window.onfocus = function () { setTimeout(function () { window.close(); }, 500); }
  }
  printreport();
</script>
```

I want the output after do the print stuff (after close by clicking save, cancel or X) then automaticly closes the window that i want to print. And i used chrome.

Comment: already did couldnt find solution. i still need to click the tab from other tab. only the the code on focus works. i want to close the tab instantly after close the print.

Comment: and i found link before and it didnt work on chrome

Comment: Add "chrome" to the search and you get https://stackoverflow.com/a/53967378/295783

Comment: thx. so the first link is for IE and the second is for Chrome

Comment: https://tests.caniuse.com/?feat=beforeafterprint